# Commas and nicknames

Tags: commas, nicknames

I want to know, do you have to use a comma after a nickname WITH a name? Like would it be "Rose darling, how are you?" or "Rose, darling, how are you?" I'm curious to know what is the correct way to use it.

Comment: As there is no real scope for confusion here, I'd choose whether to include thefirst comma in line with whether or not I wanted a pause in reading aloud/reading mentally. The second comma (or a dash or ellipsis) is necessary to set off the whole vocative

Answer (score 4):

Placing commas on either side of the nickname marks it clearly as a non-restrictive appositive.  In short, it's clear that "darling" is a re-statement of "Rose" which does not limit or identify Rose in any further way.

Omitting the first comma works, but it might tie the name and the nickname together, as if to suggest that "Rose" is really "Rose darling" in the speaker's mind.  I suppose we could also envision a typographical error in which Rose Darling is really the person named in what would then look like an expletive of direct address.

Omitting the second comma creates a dicier situation, I think.

I think using both commas is the safest choice, although cases could be made for other punctuation.  Such variations might be useful in, say, a dramatic script, where punctuation can direct an actor's phrasing.

Comment: Punctuation is seen by many as a legitimate way of directing phrasing where other considerations do not take priority (though others consider everyone should stick rigidly to the set of rules they [the 'others'] like best).